# vagrant puppet is stuck when downloading package

Tags: python-2.7, vagrant, pip, puppet

trying to get vagrant to run up my test environment but when I try to start up I get this error:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with base.pp...
==> default: notice: Scope(Class[Sandbox]): Setting up sandbox box
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]//Exec[update_apt]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: notice: /Stage[main]/sandbox/Package[http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/hurry.filesize/hurry.filesize-0.9.tar.gz]/ensure: created
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/sandbox/Exec[update_pip]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command '/usr/bin/pip'
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/sandbox/Exec[update_python_packages]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command '/usr/bin/pip'
==> default: notice: Finished catalog run in 5.94 seconds
```

Now I think the main problem is here :

```
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/sandbox/Exec[update_pip]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command '/usr/bin/pip'
==> default: err: /Stage[main]/sandbox/Exec[update_python_packages]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command '/usr/bin/pip'
```

I traced it back to my base.pp file. I think the issue lies here.

```
 95   exec { "update_pip":
 96     command => "/usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pip",
 97   }
 98 
 99   exec { "update_python_packages":
100     command => "/usr/bin/pip install -r /vagrant/requirements.txt",
101   }
```

how do I install pip if it says I cant use "/usr/bin/pip.." ?

I'm pretty new to vagrant so let me know if I n00b'd up anything. thanks.

Comment: how do you install python ?

Comment: What Vagrant image are you using?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes its installed

Comment: @MattSchuchard latest 1.92

Comment: installed ok but how ? do you install yourself using an exec command or do you use a puppet mode

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I use base.pp to do the installation.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I used the exec, sorry I didn't understand what you meant. (n00b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I ended up getting around everything:

New code:

```
 90   exec { "update_pip":
 91     command => "/usr/bin/env pip install --upgrade pip",
 92   }
 93   exec { "update_python_packages":
 94     command => "/usr/bin/env pip install -r /vagrant/requirements.txt",
 95   }
```

Original code

```
 98
 99 #  exec { "update_pip":
100 #    command => "/usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pip",
101 #  }
102 #
103 #  exec { "update_python_packages":
104 #    command => "/usr/bin/pip install -r /vagrant/requirements.txt",
105 #  }
```

What I noticed was happening is that it couldnt find the /usr/bin/pip so instead I used the env flag which I believe means upgrade wherever its installed. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [this module](https://forge.puppet.com/stankevich/python) to handle installation of Python and all related stuff. Exec login in Puppet can be pretty hard so it is almost always better to let some well established module to handle it.

This simple resource can ensure that pip will be installed and available in your path.

```
class { 'python' :
  version    => 'system',
  pip        => 'present',
  dev        => 'absent',
  virtualenv => 'absent',
  gunicorn   => 'absent',
```

}

You can even tell Puppet to create virtualenv and run  `pip install -r requirements` in some directory thanks to Puppet module that I linked.

If you do not want to use external modules I would suggest to log in to Vagrant machine and double check if pip is installed and available. You can run `which pip` to see the exact path that you need to specify to use to run pip in exec resource.